# Advanced Rest Client Desktop App Self Signed Certificate issue

Tags: self-signed, advanced-rest-client

Recently `Advanced Rest client` is changed to desktop app instead of `chrome extension`. Earlier browser used to trust the `self signed certs` but now this is a desktop app so the same work around is not working.

How to trust self signed certs in `ARC desktop app`?

Comment: I moved to Postman. It works like charm. Have a nice plugin support.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update: September 2016**

Use the "Use XHR" switch placed in the main toolbar to switch between app's transport implementation and Chrome's.
You'll be required to install additional extension that behaves as a proxy between the app and Chrome but you'll be able to pass expired certificates.

Though, I still encourage you to use valid certificate in development environment. With service like letsencrypt.org it can be mostly automated and integrated into development workflow.

**Original answer**

You can install certificate in Chrome / System and it will work.

There is a tutorial how to do it
http://restforchrome.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/advanced-rest-client.html
However there are plenty of tutorials explaining installation on different platforms.

Also I strongly encourage to use services like https://letsencrypt.org/ which provides free certificates. They also provide easy setup scripts for different servers.